# In Sandman: A Game of You: Why were Weirdzos used instead of Bizarros?

Tags: comics, the-sandman, vertigo-comics

In Sandman Vol 5: "A Game of You", Wanda dreams of Weirdzos which are the same as Bizarros from Superman lore.

Indeed [this site](http://www.holycow.com/dreaming/lore/the-sandman-frequently-asked-questions/) notes a misprint:

> The word “Bizarro” that had accidentally appeared in Sandman #32, has
>   been changed back to “Weirdzo”. (DC had nixed the use of the word
>   “Bizarro” and “Weirdzo” was used instead. When #32 was printed, one of
>   the “Weirdzo”s had fallen off revealing the “Bizarro” underneath.)

and a comment on [this site](http://www.goodgirlsgonegeek.com/2011/07/sandman-re-read-a-game-of-you/) says:

> As an old Superman fan, I quickly figured out who Weirdzo and Lila
>   were; obviously, Bizarro and Lois Lane. But this is a DC imprint; why
>   couldn’t the real ones be used? Well…, I guess DC didn’t like the
>   idea, somehow.

This [question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/why-did-gaiman-stop-using-superheroes-in-sandman), seems to note that it was Gaiman's choice to stop using heroes, but that doesn't quite gel with the misprint noted above in this case.

I haven't been able to find why DC apparently didn't want Bizarro being used. I am assuming that it was down to a Vertigo / Mature Readers imprint vs normal DCU issue, but can't find for sure.

Does anyone know the full story here?

Comment: I would imagine that since Sandman takes place in the DC universe, they would not quite have Superman comics, as in the real world. So, rather than Bizarro, their comics talk of Weirdzo, etc. (In Watchmen we have pirate comics rather than superheroes. Marvel is different, as Marvel comics exist there.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In "The Annotated Sandman" Gaiman is quoted on the subject (I found a reference including the text [here](http://www.arschkrebs.de/sandman/annotations/sandman.32.shtml)) as saying

> "The production error on that was the funniest thing about
>     it. I wrote it as **the Bizarros**, because I thought nobody
>     would mind,  what with them being out of continuity; they **vanished off
>     in CRISIS, so I thought nobody would mind my having them as comic
>     characters.  And some people at DC did.**  And so, after it was already
>     lettered, somebody went in and stuck 'Weirdzo' over all the places where
>     it said 'Bizarro'...except one fell off and confused everybody.  I've
>     heard wonderful conspiracy theories about that, but one simply fell off.
>     By the time Shawn McManus drew the second issue, he knew it had to be
>     different, so the character has a big 'H' for 'Hyperman' on his chest,
>     instead of a big 'S'."

(bold highlights by me).

Also from *The Sandman Companion*, written by Hy Bender:

> **HB**: Now that you mention it, I was wondering why the characters in the dream are called "Weirdzos", when they are clearly meant to be the Bizzaros from old *Action* and *Superman* comics.
>
> **NG**: They *were* Bizzaros in my script, but some of DC's Superman people caught sight of the story and wouldn't green-lit it. Therefore, I simply changed a few names around: Superman became Hyperman, Lois Lane became Lila Lake, and Bizzaros became Weirdzos.

And in an interview with Chip Kidd for the 20th anniversary of *The Sandman* (starts at 1:00:01):

So it was DC after all who didn't like it.

Answer (score -1):

For those of you who think DC Comics don't exist in the DC Universe, read more Superman. Superman serials and movies were made with Supe's consent, and he often had adventures with a George Reeves stand in who was the Superman actor in the comics.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please don't post comments as answers; the question was about Weirdzos vs. Bizarros so that is what you should respond to.  You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: ... and when you gain a few more reputation points, you will be able to post comments.